# Variable undefined in simple matlab function

Tags: matlab, octave, ode45

I cannot understand why I am receiving the following error:

```
error: 'y' undefined near line 7 column 22
error: execution exception in odefun.m
```

For this function:

```
function s = odefun(t, y)
        global K = [ 0.5; 3; 1; 4; 1; 5 ];
        function ret = k(n)
                global K;
                ret = K(n+1);
        end
        s = zeros(6,1);
        s(1) = k(0) -k(1) * y(1) * y(2);
        s(2) = k(2) - k(1) * y(1) * y(2);
        s(3) = k(1) * y(1) * y(2) - k(3) * y(3);
        s(4) = k(1) * y(1) * y(2) - k(2) * y(4);
        s(5) = k(3) * y(3) - k(4) * y(5);
        s(6) = k(3) * y(3) - k(5) * y(6);
end

y0 = [1; 1; 1/2; 0; 0; 0]
[t, y] = ode45(odefun, [0 10], y0)
```

Obviously I am a beginner with Matlab and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
[t, y] = ode45(odefun, [0 10], y0)
```

you are calling `odefun` without arguments. You need to pass the function handle:

```
[t, y] = ode45(@odefun, [0 10], y0)
```

Comment: Octave says handles to nested functions are not yet supported... do you know if this has been fixed? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @jaslibra Try to define your function at the end of your file, after the main function. Nested functions are functions defined inside the body of another function. But you can also define private functions after the main function. Those are different because they don't have access to the scope of the main function. I hope you can take a handle to those in Octave.